# UICollectionViewCell sizing issue when rotating the iphone on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swift3

Currently I am working on a task where I am suppose expand UICollectionView cells based on the label inside. I am written constraints programmatically for this. The resizing occurs during this call.

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributedFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()
    let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
    var frame = layoutAttributes.frame
    frame.size.width = ceil(size.width)
    layoutAttributes.frame = frame
    return layoutAttributes
}
```

This code works fine as expected, however, when I try to rotate, the cells which didn't appeared before rotation, the cells doesn't expand for them.

Is there any call I can make at cellForRowAtIndex or else place to force this preferredLayout to be called every time?

Or is there any easier process than this to avoid this calculation and directly update the cell size? I have updated estimateSize in layout, but I still need to call this method.

Answer (score 0):

use viewWillTransition method

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```